# How do i use function if i need to define it later?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, undefined, node-serialport

So, I'm using node.js, express and serialport. What I need to do is to let user pick serial port which listens to, initialize it by using AJAX request and, hopefully, get some data from serial port.
But I can't actually initizalize SerialPort object somewhere in the middle of the code, because it starts raining with "is not defined" errors. So, my code should look like this:

```
//some definitions here...
app.post('/submitPort', (req, res) => {
    tty = new SerialPort(req.body.portpath)
})
tty.on('data', () => {...})
```

And so on. Even when I'm trying to declare *tty* earlier in the code, before *submitPort*, it throws bunch of errors about that it's not defined.
And I understand this logic - I haven't initialized that object before, so, how could I do it? But that also didn't work, I mean, I tried to do it like so:

```
let tty = new SerialPort()
//some logic
app.post('/submitPort', (req, res) => {
     tty = new SerialPort(req.body.portpath)
})
```

So, I'm lost now. I **really** need to bind web and serial together, hovewer, it glues pretty hard. What am I supposed to do in order to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `lazy init` and `singleton`, then this solution can be used.

```
const tty;
//some definitions here...
app.post('/submitPort', (req, res) => {
  if(!tty){
    initTTY(req.body.portpath)
  } // not define init
  res.send("DONE")
})
function initTTY(port) {
  tty = new SerialPort(port)
  tty.on('data', () => {
    // Do something here
  })
  tty.on('error', () => {
    tty = null; // so that can initialized
  })
}
```

Comment: That's an idea. I havent thought that we run code in "parallel", and we could register event listeners within some other function, where it already will be initialized.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
let tty = undefined;

// Your business logic...

app.post('/submit-port', (req, res) => {
   tty = new SerialPort(req.body.portpath);
   tty.on('data', () => { /*  TODO: implement the handler */ });
});
```

You can consider the endpoint an "initializer" for your tty client. Now you're sure that your instance is initialized before using it.

Comment: Thats also good one, but marked answer contains a check for tty, and also wraps it in function. But that one still makes sense.

Comment: Happy to be helpful. Happy Easter.